# Replace avenue and street with divisor regex using C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have the following data:

## INPUT

```
10 AVE    2 ST
NORTH 100 AVE 5 TERR
S 39 AVE NW
S 39 AVE 1R
S 39 AVE  234 S
```

When the text "AVE" is found followed by one or more numeric digits, is should add a forward slash as follows:  (And eliminate extra spaces)

## OUTPUT

```
10 AVE / 2 ST
NORTH 100 AVE / 5 TERR
S 39 AVE NW
S 39 AVE 1R
S 39 AVE / 234 S
```

I have something but not quite working since it is eliminating other characters:

```
address = Regex.Replace(address.ToUpper(), @"AVE\s\d", "/");
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `address = Regex.Replace(address.ToUpper(), @"\bAVE\s+([0-9]+)\b", "AVE / $1");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
address = Regex.Replace(address.ToUpper(), @"(AVE)\s+(?=\d+\b)", "$1 / ");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z2JVw7/2/). Add `\b` before `AVE` if it should be matched as a whole word.

*Details*:

- `(AVE)` - `AVE` captured into Group 1 (`$1`)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=\d+\b)` - followed with one or more digts that are followed with a word boundary.

Note the following is equivalent in terms of result:

```cs
Regex.Replace(address.ToUpper(), @"(?<=AVE)\s+(?=\d+\b)", " / ")
Regex.Replace(address.ToUpper(), @"AVE\s+(\d+)\b", "AVE / $1")
```